# Javascript : Upload Image file and resize to different resolution then download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-processing, html5-canvas

Please suggest some library for Image processing.

We tried to draw image to canvas and then to download the image of required size, but not achievable.

We like to use this mechanism to reduce image processing in back-end server

Below is the code we tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Image Resize</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>  
    <input id="filez" type="file" value="img">
    <div id="parentDiv"></div>  
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    function ImageResizeObject(parentElement,fileElement,objz){
        this.parentElement = $(parentElement);
        this.fileElement = document.getElementById(fileElement);
        this.objz = objz;
        this.imageFile = this.fileElement.files[0];

        this.parentElement.empty();

        for(var i=0;i<this.objz.length;i++){
            var parentDiv = $("<div></div>");
            parentDiv.attr("id","parentDiv parentDiv"+i);
            var canvas = $("<canvas id='parentDivCanvas"+i+"'></canvas>");
            canvas.css({"height":objz[i].height,"width":this.objz[i].width});
            parentDiv.append(canvas);
            this.parentElement.append(parentDiv);

            var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();          
            img.src =URL.createObjectURL(this.imageFile);                  
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0, 0,canvas.width(),canvas.height());

        }
    }

    $("#filez").on('change', function(){
        console.log("file uploaded");
        FileUpload = new ImageResizeObject("#parentDiv","filez",[{"height":"410","width":"410"},{"height":"205","width":"205"}]);                       
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

*On Stackoverflow, we don't make library recommendations, but...*

**You can use html5 canvas to resize images.**

- Create a canvas element
- Size it to your desired scaled size
- Draw the image onto the canvas with scaling to the desired size
- Create a resized imageObject using the canvas as the image.src

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

[image]

```js
var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/marioRunningRight1.png";
function start(){
    resizeImg(img,0.50);
    resizeImg(img,2);
}

function resizeImg(img,scaleFactor){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
    var iw=img.width;
    var ih=img.height;
    c.width=iw*scaleFactor;
    c.height=ih*scaleFactor;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,iw*scaleFactor,ih*scaleFactor);
    var scaledImg=new Image();
    scaledImg.onload=function(){
        // scaledImg is a scaled imageObject for upload/download
        // For testing, just append it to the DOM
        document.body.appendChild(scaledImg);
    }
    scaledImg.src=c.toDataURL();
}
```

```html
<h4>Original image</h4>
<img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/marioRunningRight1.png' crossOrigin='anonymous'>
<br>
<h4>Resized images at 50% and at 200%</h4>
```

Comment: I can't argue with this answer. One thing I'd highlight is that the attempt to resize the canvas in the original code fails because of this line:

canvas.css({"height":objz[i].height,"width":this.objz[i].width});

That line changes the canvas's styled dimensions, not its drawing dimensions. To change the drawing dimensions, you need to change the canvas's width and height attributes - as shown in the code above.